# How to plot bars in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the question that seems to be basic.
I have a dataframe and want to plot out of some columns(busLine, PassengerCount, departure_time, destination_time)

| Line | PassengerCount | departure_time | destination_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC03 | 11 | 2019-12-18 06:00:00 | 2019-12-18 06:30:00 |
| CV47 | 24 | 2019-12-18 06:00:00 | 2019-12-18 06:30:00 |
| DC15 | 1 | 2019-12-18 05:30:00 | 2019-12-18 06:00:00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to plot in x-axis[departure_time,destination_time], y-axis PassengerCount and label the bars with Line (AC03, CV47, DC15) according to times and passenger count.
I am very new to pandas and finding it difficult to achieve. Please, how to approach that efficiently?

Comment: thanks @henry for editing

Answer (score 0):

There are a few graphing libraries that you could use. The most standard is matplotlib. The one I enjoy the most is plotly, because it creates interactive graphs that let you hover over specific data points to see the underlying data. Plotly also IMO has a much nicer API that makes creating the graphs much simpler.

To create a your bar chart in plotly, you can do this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Departure Time', x=df['departure_time'], y=df['PassengerCount'], color=df['Line']),
    go.Bar(name='Destination Time', x=df['destination_time'], y=df['PassengerCount'], color=df['Line'])
])
```

I think that should do the trick!

If writing out that code doesn't come naturally, there are also a few python packages that give you a GUI for creating these graphs, one of which I'm actually the creator of. If you're interested, checkout [Mito](https://trymito.io/so).

Comment: thanks @Aaron! But how to the fig variable?

Comment: to display the chart, you can use `fig.show()`

Comment: it seems color is not a valid property anymore, bgcolor should be used, I think